# Marginalization from randomly-spaced grids of the joint distribution

Tags: r, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I have the vectors of co-ordinates of the grid points $(x, y)$ and the joint probability values, $z$. Could you recommend a way to do marginalization for the below joint distribution? (In my problem, I have random sampled grid points from the joint distribution. Of course, if the points were lined up on straight lines then this is not so difficult).

[image: irregular grids]

Comment: I guess one approach is to do some sort of interpolation